# Prolog - get_code/1 without prompt

Tags: input, prolog, prompt

If I try to input a character of input by calling get_code/1 like this, there is a prompt displayed.

```
?- get_code(C).
|: a
C = 97.
```

This works as I would expect, but I want to input characters without drawing the prompt for this specific call (I may want to draw it again later). As of now, I am doing this:

```
my_get_code(C) :- prompt1(''), get_code(C).
```

Which works, but is there a better or more proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
char_code(Char,Code) . %BuiltIn

?- char_code(a,N).
N = 97 ? ;
```

or

```
?- C=0'a.
C = 97 ?
```

or 
tape this

```
?-C="a".
C = [97] ? ;
no
```