# Prolog How to use get_code in a pl file

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I want to print a ASCII value of a character. I am using GNU prolog.

Everything I have tried during 1h hasn't worked. So I came here and I have seen this post: [Prolog - get_code/1 without prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891108/prolog-get-code-1-without-prompt)

However, For every character in input, It write 10. Here is my code :

```
my_get_code(C) :- get_linedit_prompt(''), get_code(C).

/*
lower_case(X,Y) :- 
   my_get_code(X), Y = X.
*/
/*
lower :-
   read(X),
   lower_case(X,Y),
   write(Y).
*/
lower :-
   read(X),
   my_get_code(X),
   write(X).
```

In fact, my goal is to take a value of an ASCII character and then, convert uppercase into lowercase. I need to get tha ascii value and then add 32 in order to have the lower_case value.

Comment: `get_code(C), Cl is C + 32, put_code(Cl).` This should take uppercase char and print corresponding lower case char. I am not exactly sure what else you are asking?